# Make gazebo camera ignore certain objects

Tags: ros, gazebo, sensor, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot model with a camera in gazebo. The camera is observing the world but some objects I would like the camera to ignore so they are not captured in the image output. Is it possible to have a gazebo camera ignore certain objects e.g. perceive them as transparent or black e.g. by giving the objects a specific prefix in their name or something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201558/make-gazebo-camera-ignore-certain-objects/) by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Gazebo developers have requested that questions like this be asked on http://answers.gazebosim.org/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0